# Find a (nearly) optimal route among several locations that can be found by Google Maps

Tags: java, dependency-injection, pathfinding

The README should give you all of the information you need for a comprehensive review, and if it doesn't then please say so.

If you would like to contribute a review but do not have time or desire to review all 600 or so lines, a review of one class would be welcome. If you want a suggestion on where to start looking, I know `me.psanders.ShortRouteFinder` has a rather huge method that I'm not quite sure how best to split up. It is the first class reached after the Entry Point in `me.psanders.TspSolver`. I include that class below, but the rest can be found at the github link.

https://github.com/hxtk/Road-Trip-Router

```
package me.psanders;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.commons.cli.MissingOptionException;
import org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.cli.OptionGroup;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.GnuParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
import org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException;

import com.google.maps.DirectionsApi;
import com.google.maps.DistanceMatrixApi;
import com.google.maps.DistanceMatrixApiRequest;
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;
import com.google.maps.model.DistanceMatrixElement;
import com.google.maps.model.DistanceMatrix;
import com.google.maps.model.TravelMode;
import com.google.maps.errors.ApiException;

import me.psanders.graph.path.Cycle;
import me.psanders.graph.path.HCycleFinder;
import me.psanders.graph.path.GeneticOptimizationStrategy;
import me.psanders.graph.MatrixGraph;

/** Factory class for Cycle based on a list of geographic locations.
 *
 * <p>We pass in a list of arguments that are used to create a Google Maps
 * API instance, look up the set of places from that list, and optimize a
 * route between those places using a Genetic Algorithm.
 *
 * <p>The arguments are designed to be formatted as arguments coming in from
 * the command line, i.e., the <code>args</code> passed to a program entry.
 *
 * <p>Distinct places are delimited by the distinct elements of the array.
 * Consult your command line's documentation for more information. Usually
 * you will group using quotes ('"') or escaped spaces ('\ ').
 */
public class ShortRouteFinder {

  private String[] args;

  public ShortRouteFinder(String[] args) {
    this.args = args;
  }

  /** Parse command line arguments and deliver a route between the points listed.
   *
   */
  public Cycle getRoute() {
    Options options = getOptions();

    try {
      CommandLine flags = new GnuParser().parse(options, args);

      // Print help if the user asked for it or if we cannot proceed.
      if (flags.hasOption("help")) {
        usage(options);
        System.exit(0);
      }

      String[] places = getPlaces(flags);
      if (places.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("You must provide at least two locations.");
        usage(options);
        System.exit(1);
      }

      // Retrieve the matrix of distances between each pair of places passed in to args.
      DistanceMatrix distMatrix = getDistMatrix(flags, places);

      // Generate the list of labels to look up matrix indices.
      HashMap<String, Integer> labels = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < places.length; ++i) {
        labels.put(places[i], i);
      }

      // Convert the DistanceMatrix object to a 2D array for the MatrixGraph.
      Long[][] matrix = new Long[places.length][places.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < places.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < places.length; ++j) {
          if (i == j) continue;  // Skip the diagonal axis.

          DistanceMatrixElement element = distMatrix.rows[i].elements[j];
          switch (element.status) {
            case NOT_FOUND:
              System.out.println("We couldn't resolve \"" + places[i]
                  + "\" so we're trying to route around it.");
              // Fallthrough
            case ZERO_RESULTS:
              // The algorithm will optimize away from this leg if the cost is arbitrarily high.
              matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i] = Long.MAX_VALUE / 2;
              break;
            default:
              if (flags.hasOption("fast")) {
                matrix[i][j] = element.duration.inSeconds;
              } else {
                matrix[i][j] = element.distance.inMeters;
              }
          }
        }
      }

      // Find the optimal route.
      return new HCycleFinder(
          new MatrixGraph<>(labels, matrix),
          new GeneticOptimizationStrategy<String, Long>(new Random())
      ).getOptimalCycle();

    // Error handling
    } catch (UnrecognizedOptionException e) {
      // This will be triggered if a user passes in a flag that is not in our list.
      System.out.println("Option \"" + e.getOption() + "\" Not found. See usage:");
      usage(options);
      System.exit(1);
    } catch (IllegalStateException | MissingOptionException e) {
      System.out.println("You must include a valid Google Maps Services API key\n");
      usage(options);
      System.exit(1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO(hxtk): Exit gracefully on exception.
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ApiException | InterruptedException | IOException e) {
      // TODO(hxtk): Exit gracefully on exception.
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }

  /** Get the distance matrix containing the distance between each pair of places passed in.
   *
   * <p>Flags are used to control the API Request. For more details, see `getOptions`.
   *
   */
  private DistanceMatrix getDistMatrix(CommandLine flags, String[] places)
      throws IllegalStateException, InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().
        apiKey(flags.getOptionValue("key")).build();

    DistanceMatrixApiRequest request = DistanceMatrixApi.
        getDistanceMatrix(context, places, places);

    if (flags.hasOption("scenic")) {
      request = request.avoid(DirectionsApi.RouteRestriction.HIGHWAYS)
          .avoid(DirectionsApi.RouteRestriction.TOLLS);
    }
    if (flags.hasOption("no-fee")) {
      request = request.avoid(DirectionsApi.RouteRestriction.TOLLS)
          .avoid(DirectionsApi.RouteRestriction.FERRIES);
    }
    if (flags.hasOption("mode")) {
      switch (flags.getOptionValue("mode")) {
        case "driving":
          request = request.mode(TravelMode.DRIVING);
          break;
        case "transit":
          request = request.mode(TravelMode.TRANSIT);
          break;
        case "bicycling":
          request = request.mode(TravelMode.BICYCLING);
          break;
        case "walking":
          request = request.mode(TravelMode.WALKING);
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Invalid transportation mode. Options include:");
          System.out.println("    driving, transit, bicycling, walking");
      }
    }

    return request.await();
  }

  /** Produces a parser that will process the arguments below:
   *
   * <code>
   * -F,--no-fee        Selects route that avoids toll roads and ferries.
   * -f,--file <FILE>   Reads newline-delimited locations from a file.
   * --fast             Selects route with shortest time.
   *                    (Default is shortest distance)
   * -h,--help          Print this usage message.
   * -k,--key <KEY>     Google Maps Services API Key.
   * -M,--mode <arg>    Transportation mode (uses Google default)
   *                    Options: "driving" "transit" "bicycling" "walking"
   * -s,--scenic        Selects route that avoids highways and toll roads.
   * </code>
   */
  private Options getOptions() {
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption(
        OptionBuilder
            .withLongOpt("key")
            .hasArg().withArgName("KEY")
            .withDescription("Google Maps Services API Key (Required).")
            .isRequired()
            .create("k")
    );
    options.addOption("h", "help", false, "Print this usage message.");

    OptionGroup modifiers = new OptionGroup();
    modifiers.addOption(
        OptionBuilder
            .withLongOpt("mode")
            .hasArg().withArgName("MODE")
            .withDescription("Transportation mode (uses Google default).\n"
                + "Options: \"driving\" \"transit\" \"bicycling\" \"walking\"")
            .create("m")
    );
    modifiers.addOption(
        OptionBuilder
            .withLongOpt("no-fee")
            .withDescription("Selects route that avoids toll roads and ferries.")
            .create("F")
    );
    modifiers.addOption(
        OptionBuilder
            .withLongOpt("scenic")
            .withDescription("Selects route that avoids highways and toll roads.")
            .create("s")
    );
    modifiers.addOption(
        OptionBuilder
            .withLongOpt("fast")
            .withDescription("Selects route with shortest time.\n(Default is shortest distance.)")
            .create()
    );
    options.addOptionGroup(modifiers);

    // Commented out by hxtk (2017-11-29) pending logic for file IO in `ShortRouteFinder.getPlaces`.
    //options.addOption(
    //   OptionBuilder
    //        .withLongOpt("file")
    //        .hasArg().withArgName("FILE")
    //        .withDescription("Reads newline-delimited locations from a file.")
    //        .create("f")
    //);
    return options;
  }

  /** Return a list of locations among which we will find our cycle.
   *
   * <p>The flags provided will change the behavior of this method. If there is a "file" flag,
   * we will attempt to open the file named as that flag's argument and read newline-delimited
   * locations from that file. Otherwise, any unconsumed arguments are assumed to be locations.
   */
  private String[] getPlaces(CommandLine flags) {
    if (flags.hasOption("file")) {
      // TODO(hxtk): Handle file input.
      return new String[0];
    } else {
      return flags.getArgs();
    }
  }

  /** Print the usage message for the given options.
   *
   * For more information, see the documentation for HelpFormatter:
   *     https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html#UsageHelp
   *     https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/HelpFormatter.html
   */
  private void usage(Options options) {
    new HelpFormatter().printHelp("RoutePlanner",
        "Find a (nearly) optimal route for your next road trip.\n\n", options,
        "\n\nPlease report any bugs or comments to "
        +"https://github.com/hxtk/Road-Trip-Router/issues",
true);
  }
}
```

I'm continuing to work on this, and will periodically sync this post with the GitHub repository until the first comment or response comes in. For the most recent version of the file I've shown above, see: https://github.com/hxtk/Road-Trip-Router/blob/master/src/main/java/me/psanders/ShortRouteFinder.java